# Set a profile in Tasker to wipe the phone

Tags: security, tasker

Is it possible to create a profile in Tasker that completely wipes the phone?

I ask because I haven't tried Tasker yet, and this might be enough to make me buy it. It doesn't matter how this profile would be triggered, I'm interested in the effect. It has to completely reset my phone's internal memory. Preferably, it would also erase the SDcard, but that's not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it can or not, but Tasker has a 7 day free trial if you download it from their website instead of android market.

http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html

So you can try it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands right now, Tasker doesn't have that functionality. Some researching *indicates*
 no third-party app can do that.